# CSS Blur effect does not work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use blur filter in my website but it doesn't work. I don't know how to fix it.

```
#main {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("tlo.jpg");
    filter: blur(10px);
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: In what browser? http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters It won't work in IE, and Chrome appears to require a `-webkit-` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

try using vendor prefixes:

```
#main {
height:100vh;
background-image: url("tlo.jpg");
-moz-filter:blur(10px);
-o-filter:blur(10px);
-webkit-filter:blur(10px);
filter:blur(10px);
background-size: cover;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using vendor prefixes as they are not supported directly