# sand glass effect only with css

Tags: html, css, menu, blur

trying to blur out background div of menubar so it blurs out page content as user scrolls but it blurs itself and not the background content which is on z-index 0. Where do I make mistake? (opacity is not a problem, I have tested that) Thanks for help.

I used this stack answer for help [CSS Blur effect does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460071/css-blur-effect-does-not-work)

this is my css

```
.menuwrapper {
background-color: rgba(250,250,250, 0.1);
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 42px;
z-index: 1;
margin: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.menuwrapper::before{
  content: '';
  margin: -35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: blur(10px);
    -moz-filter:blur(10px);
    -o-filter:blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter:blur(10px);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

this is my html:

```
div class="menuwrapper"  data-aos="slide-down" data-aos-delay="1800" data-aos-duration="500">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="leftmenu"><a href="#intro"><img src="main_media/logo_kvarteto_black.png" alt="logo Sláčikové kvarteto Art" height="48" width="48" style="position:absolute;top:-3px"></a></div>
            <div class="rightmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="anchor" href="#kontakt">KONTAKT</a></li>
                    <li><a class="anchor" href="#galeria">FOTO & VIDEO</a></li>
                    <li><a class="anchor" href="#clenovia">ČLENOVIA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#repertoar">REPERTOÁR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#kdehrame">KDE HRÁME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#intro">DOMOV</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

result of code above:[image]

Comment: add your html also

Comment: ah i see, blur should be applied to the element itself and not another element above it

Comment: what? The result i want is to have menubar which has blurred background so when users scroll the content of the page gets dynamically blurred.

Comment: you are applied blur on pseudo element and not navbar, so simply remove background of navback and use the pseudo element as the background. and remove this `margin: -35px;`

Comment: than you, tried it, cleared cache but no success. so mistake is somewhere else

Comment: can you share link ?

Comment: ok, can you please send me some message here privately?

Answer (score -1):

You have to make a div that covers the area you want to blur.

```
<div id="glassLayer" style="width:100%">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: that is actually doing it if you dont set height and width it is automatically doing what your code does.  check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460071/css-blur-effect-does-not-work so mistake is somewhere else